# On trichotomy of order for natural numbers

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am currently going through Chapter 2 of Tao's Analysis book, and I don't quite understand the proof of the Trichotomy of order for natural numbers (Proposition 2.2.13).

Let $a,b$ be natural numbers. Then exactly one of the following statements is true: $a<b,a=b,b<a$.

The proof goes as follows (reproduced from the book itself). First we show that we cannot have more than one of the statements holding at the same time. If $a<b$ then $a\neq b$ by definition, and if $a>b$ then $a\neq b$ by definition. If $a<b$ and $b<a$, then we would have that $a=b$, which is a contradiction. Thus, no more than one of the statements is true.

My question is in regard to the proof strategy that is being used for this part. I do understand what is going on, it makes sense to me. I see that the first two cases are to say that if one of the statements happen, then the other two cannot happen and the third case says that if the three happen at the same time, that's impossible.

I want to ask what's the proof strategy that is being followed (I'm relatively new to proof writing, so I need to have it clear in my head), because this is the first proof of this kind I have seen.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't see how $a < b$ and $b < a$ together somehow imply $a=b$

Comment: Tao uses anti-symmetry of the order to justify this, but I do understand your point

Comment: Oh, I see, good point

Comment: The goal here is to prove exactly one of the following 3 statements is true for any a, b, and your book's proof strategy is proof by contradiction by claiming there may be two statements simultaneously true.  There're only 3 cases (unordered pairs of statements) out of the 3 statements here, so the author discussed those 3 cases each of which arrived at contradiction. So the original goal is achieved.

Comment: Presumably you have already established that at least one of $a<b,a=b,a>b$ must be true. E.g. suppose $a<^* b$ means $1<b/a\in\Bbb N.$ Then $3\not <^* 4$ and $3\ne 4$ and $4\not <^* 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third edition he cites Prop. 2.2.12 as containing the statement which is used to conclude $a = b$ from $a < b \land b < a$. But to be honest I don't see any statement that immediately implies this. Prop. 2.2.12 does contain the anti-symmetry law, but anti-symmetry refers to $\leq$ and can therefore not be used on $a < b \land b < a$.

What is needed here is the transitivity of $<$ ; since $a < b \land b < a$ then implies $a < a $ which already gives the desired contradiction.

The overall idea of that first part is to show
$$
 \neg (a < b \land a = b)  ~\land~ \neg (b < a \land a = b) ~\land~ \neg (a < b \land b < a) 
$$
porving that ***at most one*** of the 3 parts of the disjuction $a < b \lor a = b \lor b < a$ is true. The second part of the proof (as found in the book) then shows by induction that the disjunction is true and therefore ***at least one*** of the parts must be true.

Comment: Why is not the case that we want to show that $[a<b/land/neg (b<a)/land/neg (a/neq b)]\lor [b<a/land/neg (a<b)/land/neg (a/neq b)]\lor [a=b/land/neg(a<b)/land/neg (b<a)]$?

Comment: @AlexRuiz Yes $(a < b \land \neg b < a \land a \neq b) \lor (\neg a < b \land b < a \land a \neq b) \lor (\neg a < b \land \neg b < a \land a = b)$ is indeed what we want to show overall. And it follows from the first part of the proof (which I specified) combined with the second part, which shows $a<b∨a=b∨b<a$ by induction.

Comment: My apologies, I couldn't work these past couple of days. So from what I just worked out, $\neg (a<b\land a=b) \land \neg (b<a\land a=b)\land \neg (a<b\land b<a)$ is equivalent to saying $a<b \lor b<a \lor a=b$. I must say this is a very smart equivalence, am I right?

Comment: @AlexRuiz They are not logically equivalent. If $A$ and $B$ are both true, then $\neg(A \land B) \land \neg (C \land B) \land \neg (A \land B)$ is false, but $A \lor B \lor C$ is true. The first one is saying "from $A, B, C$ at most one can be true" and the second one tells you that "at least one of $A, B, C$ is true". And in the proof both parts are shown for $A \equiv a < b$, $B \equiv a = b$ and $C \equiv b < a$.

Answer (score 1):

The basic proof strategy is this:

First: to establish that exactly one of the three claims hold, you typically show two things:

1. That at least one of the two claims hold
2. That at most one of the two claims hold

Please note that in your post, you only describe a proof for the second half, but I am sure the first half is provided in the book as well

Second, to establish that at most one of several claims hold, all you have to show is that you cannot have any of the two claims holding at once: if you show that, then clearly you also cannot have three or more claims holding.  This is what the proof does: it rules out all combinations of two claims: the first and the second can't hold together, the second and the third can't hold together, and the first and the third can't hold together.

Your analysis is actually a little off on that last one: it's not that the proof shows that you can't have all three, but simply that you can't have $a < b$ and $b < a$ at the same time, because if you do then, you have $a=b$, and now you have both $a < b$ and $a = b$, which some earlier theorem must already have ruled out.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, so in this type of proofs it's just standard to prove those two things yuo mentioned? It's just that it's hard for me to see how each proof shows each of these two goals. I don't really see the difference

Comment: @AlexRuiz Sorry, but I am not quite clear what you just asked here. First, yes, it is totally standard to prove 'exactly one' by proving 'at least one' and 'at most one'. But again, in your post you only provide a proof of 'at most one' .... I am sure Tao also provides a proof of 'at least one', but you are not reporting that part in your original post. Second, it is defintely *not* true that 'each proof shows each of these goals'! If I show 'at most one', I have not shown 'at least one', and vice versa. This is why you need to do both.